# GraphViz doesn't make a png file when it is started from C# code

Tags: c#, graphviz

In my class describing graph I would like to make one method generating GraphViz code and save it to the .dot file, and other making png graphics file with that graph. I tried:

```
        private void MakeDotFile()
        {
            FileStream fileStream =
                new FileStream("tmp.dot", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            streamWriter.Write("graph { a -- b }");
            streamWriter.Close();
            fileStream.Close();
        }

        public void MakePngFile()
        {
            MakeDotFile();
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo =
                new ProcessStartInfo("<< dot.exe location >>",
                "-Tpng << .dot file location >> > << .png file location >>");
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

but unfortunately it is finishing making a terible sound like "beep" and doing nothing (not creating png file). When I debugged, I had found that process exit code is 3. I checked many times if paths are good. Interesting is that the same program with the same arguments in cmd.exe is running right.
What do you think? Where is the problem? What is the solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the output, you should use the `-o` parameter of `dot`.

```
process.StartInfo =
    new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\graphviz\bin\dot.exe",
        @"-Tpng D:\tmp.dot -o D:\tmp.png");
```